# What does "mi yodeya" mean?

Tags: words, hebrew, stackexchange

What does "mi yodeya" mean?

Comment: Related: [The name "mi.yodeya" should really be either "mi.yodey.a" or "mi.yodey-a"](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1106/759)

Answer (score 26):

"Mi yodeya" or מי יודע in Hebrew means "who knows," where "mi" means "who" and "yodeya" is the masculine singular participle for the verb "know." This phrase is featured in the popular Passover song ["Echad Mi Yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) and on the Q&A site for Jewish life and learning [Mi Yodeya](http://mi.yodeya.com).

Answer (score 8):

It means who knows!